# python execfile; new window does not open up fully

Tags: python, execfile

I am having an issue with my execfile function.

What i would like to do is open a new file upon the click of a menu item as shown underneath. The issue however, is that when the file opens, some of its contents opens up in the window where the original menu item exists and the rest of the file opens up in a separate window.

It should all open up in a separate window and not half-here, half-there! Where am i going wrong?

```
def search():
   execfile("grid2.py")

editmenu.add_separator()

editmenu.add_command(label="Research", command=search)
```

The file grid2.py should open up just like it does when I use the run module in IDLE.

Comment: What will happen if you open grid2.py in command line? Still two windows?

Comment: no, it works correctly!

Comment: I think we need your code.